# Mongodb high CPU - many slow queries on special virtual collection db.$cmd

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

In diagnosing a high CPU mongodb, we found many slow (6-7 secs) queries. All of those are related to "ns" : "mydb.$cmd".

Slow query entry look like below :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5571b739f65f7e64bb806362"),
"op" : "command",
"ns" : "mydb.$cmd",
"command" : {
    "aggregate" : "MyCollection",
    "pipeline" : [ 
        {
            "$mergeCursors" : [ 
                {
                    "host" : "abc:27005",
                    "id" : NumberLong(82775337156)
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"keyUpdates" : 0,
"numYield" : 0,
"lockStats" : {
    "timeLockedMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(12),
        "w" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(2),
        "w" : NumberLong(2680)
    }
},
"responseLength" : 12312,
"millis" : 6142,
"execStats" : {},
"ts" : ISODate("2015-06-05T12:35:40.801Z"),
"client" : "1.1.1.1",
"allUsers" : [],
"user" : ""
```

}

We are not sure what part of code causing these queries. How shall we proceed to find / debug what queries from application causing these $cmd slow queries ?

Answer (score 1):

Those logs are actually the queries issued when running a [command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) against the specified database (mydb in your case).  This is therefore just some aggregation command being run against your MongoDB.

If your application is not doing this directly, it would appear (as documented in http://dbattish.tumblr.com/post/108652372056/joins-in-mongodb) that the $mergecursors variant is used from v2.6 to merge queries across shards.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  How can we find which query was causing this command ?

Comment: @Samba: I don't currently use mongo v2.6, so can't repro this and say for certain.  However, it looks from the article that the id in the command is in fact a cursor ID.  Can you find references to that cursor earlier in your log and then look at the query parameters and client details to track it down?

Answer (score -2):

My test shows that MongoDB uses always ~90-100% CPU when it deals with concurrent requests. This beacause I move to MySQL. My app with the thame simple queries work 3x faster with MySQL and i uses much less CPU. I will create an artciel soon with full testing. For now, just look to CPU usage of MongoDB and MariaDB for queries with X=5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000 concurrent connections.

```
siege -b -cX -t1M url
```

As I realized, high CPU usage doesn't related to hight CPU usage. I mean, even very simple queries with concurrent requests make MongoDB to use 100% CPU.

All tests with 1vCPU and 1Gb memory and connection pool size 10

MongoDB

[image]

MySQL

[image]

I did many tests with different configurations (4vCPU, 6G Memory) and always MongoDB was use more CPU then MySQL. What you can try with MongoDB is:

1. Change connection loop size. I hope you don't open connection per query.
2. Are you using Mongoose? Try with Native Nodejs MYSQL Drivers - it much faster.

I very disappointed from MongodDB for reading data. Not only that MySQL uses much less CPU, it was always at least 3x faster!

Comment: OP did not ask for a comparison of MongoDB and MySQL.